# Pull request from develop to master causing conflicts

Tags: git, pull-request

Me and my coworkers are working on separate features and when we're done we rebase onto develop before making a pull request.

When we reach a stable develop version we process to make a PR from develop into master; the trouble is that sometimes we get conflicts even though master only gets updated from develop.

How are those conflicts generated? How is it possible for some Pr from develop to master to have 2 parents?

This is a git graph of the current situation:
[master branch graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgWi9.png)

**UPDATE**

I am pretty sure that the conflict are generated by this flow:

1. We work on a feature and when done squash all of its commits and merge it into develop

```
D: a-b-c-d-e-                                                    F
F:    \__b1-b2-b3 -> squash creates F -> rebase on develop -> __/
```

2. Develop it's released to master

```
M: a-b-c-d-e-F
D: a-b-c-d-e-F
F:           F
```

3. Develop gets updates while someone keeps working on F and repeats the squash and merge process from step 1

```
M: a-b-c-d-e-F
D: a-b-c-d-e-F-g-h-i-                                                  J
F:           F -> f1-f2-f3 -> squash creates J -> rebase on develop __/
```

4. Develop it's released to master and we have potential issues

```
M: a-b-c-d-e-F - conflicts?
D: a-b-c-d-e-F-g-h-i-J
F:                   J
```

I hope I was clear enough, but in brief it seems that in step 3 we have created a second parent for the feature branch, and this is causing merge conflicts when merging from develop to master.
Is it right to use the same feature for a PR and after it gets approved work on it again, squash all its commits, rebase and then make another PR with it?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

There will be conflicts as long as the code bases of both branches are different... which would mean that there is a change on master that is not in develop. Let's do two quick mental exercises based on your question

Scenario one: branch develop is started from master. Master will never get commits. Master will only get merges (say, using `--no-ff`) from develop. There will never be any editing of anything on master (by not using `--no-commit`)... so, no tricks. In this case, everytime you merge develop on master, there will *never* be any conflict. And as a test, every merge revision on master can be compared with the revision that was merged from develop and there will be *no* differences whatsoever.

Scenario two: develop is started from master.... but  unlike scenario one, there is a change on master that is not on develop (for whatever reason: rewritten revisions with an amendment on a file, a revision that is not on develop.... anything goes to generate the difference)... everything else goes like scenario one.... in this case you will get conflicts every once in a while (when dealing with code related to the differences between the branches). This can be tested by diffing the merge revisions in master with the revision that was merged on develop. As long as there are differences there, you will get conflicts (involving those pieces of code that showed up on the diff).

Let us know.